# Example of sequence for which ratio test is unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I did the following exercise (about ratio test):

Show that if $\left | {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right |$ is unbounded then the original series $\sum_n a_n x^n$ converges only when $x=0$.

At first it seemed fairly clear that if $\left | {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right |$ is unbounded the series cannot converge: if the series converges then $a_n \to 0$ but if $\left | {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right |$ is unbounded it must be that $a_n \not\to 0$. The problem is, I can't seem to show that $a_n \not\to 0$.

Is there an example of $a_n$ and $x \neq 0$ such that $\left | {a_{n+1} \over a_n} \right |$ is unbounded and $\sum_n a_n x^n< \infty$?

Would the following provide a valid example? $a_{2n}={1\over 3^n}, a_{2n+1}={1\over 2^n}, x=1$?

Comment: Yes, it provides a valid example. The correct statement is that if $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} \left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert = +\infty,$$ then the series converges only for $x = 0$.

Comment: "If the series converges then $a_n\to0$" What makes you say this? $$1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\cdots$$ converges for $|x|<1$.

Comment: You still there, blue?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I am still here?

Comment: Good. I just thought you might want to respond to my earlier comment.

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: Author non-responsive. Question apparently abandoned.